# How to add header to Capybara requests?

Tags: capybara, ruby-on-rails-4.2, capybara-webkit

Is there a way to add HTTP header to Capybara requests/tests.

I am using the following gems.

```
capybara (2.4.4)
capybara-webkit (1.5.2)
chromedriver-helper (1.0.0)
rails (4.2.6)
```

Following is the Capybara setup:

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome

Capybara::Screenshot.register_driver(:chrome) do |driver, path|
  driver.browser.save_screenshot(path)
end
```

Comment: Your question is confusing because you show the `capybara-webkit` driver as on of your gems, but then show a selenium driver configuration, which one are you actually using?  (also your version of Capybara is pretty obsolete)

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I am using selenium driver, please ignore `capybara-webkit`

Answer (score 5):

If you're using capybara-webkit (As your Gemfile shows) you can use the `page.driver.header` method - https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit#non-standard-driver-methods . However if you are actually using selenium as the driver (as your driver registration shows) then you can't add headers without configuring a request modifying proxy of some sort (browsermob, etc).

That being said, you really should ask yourself why you want/need to set extra headers though, it's possible you're trying to test something that would be better tested directly as a request test rather than a feature/system test using Capybara

Comment: Why does it put http in front of the value?   `page.driver.header 'API_TOKEN', 'ak;dsmdncasdmnsdnsd'`, when i inspect it it says `HTTP_API_TOKEN`